# Topbar crashes browser tab with pending messages/achievements

Tags: bug, status-declined, top-bar, internet-explorer-9

In this version of Internet Explorer 9 (9.0.8112.16421) on Windows Server 2008, I can reliably crash my browser tab by doing the following actions:

1. Do whatever is needed to get inbox messages or achievement/reputation pending in the top bar.
2. Click the icon where something is pending.
3. Click this icon again

The gray-ish background from hovering over the icon will stay, the browser seems to freeze for a few seconds, then it will pop up with a message that IE stopped working. This will crash the current browser tab. (I am not certain if other SO tabs will crash as well)

If I click on the item that has been changed in step 3 instead, everything keeps working. I am not sure what happens if I click outside the menu to close it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [IE9 crashes after jquery click event](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11213615/447356)

Comment: Any chance you can upgrade to IE10 or a real browser? Of course it's not a real solution, but will save you lots of agony. Also, as a workaround you can see your inbox items [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/2543769/sumurai8?tab=inbox). :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard "Maybe it breaks something." -- Company 2013 (no, I can't; I don't use Windows Server of any OS because I love it either ;-) )

Comment: In IE 11 on win7 this doesn't repro (assuming IE11 _IS_ a real browser by the definition of the more thrustworthy members of our community)

Comment: @rene <rant>Internet Explorer is just Microsoft version of a browser, always lagging behind the standards, always lacking features etc etc... so even IE100 won't be "real browser" in my opinion same way that Pepsi will never be Coke: they can never make 100% copy.</rant> But yeah, this one is specific only to IE9, think that it doesn't crash even IE8. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Your rant is accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the browser -- we don't support your current version though, so I'm declining this.

Comment: Fair 'nuff. Have a free unicorn.